# Android – setText to Tabs in a switch case Statement

Tags: java, android

My app contains a bottomNavigationView and a TabLayout in the activity_main.xml. The selected Navigation Fragment is chosen with a switch-case and the tabs are named programmatically like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("A"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("B"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("C"));


        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.navigation_national:
                                selectedFragment = ItemOneFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.navigation_international:
                                selectedFragment = ItemTwoFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.navigation_blackboard:
                                selectedFragment = ItemThreeFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                        }
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, ItemOneFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();

    }

}
```

Now I want to change the tab names depending to the selected bottomNavigation option. Why can‘t I just add the addText(""); statements to the different cases?

Comment: you have already set the tab names...

Comment: Yes, I‘m well aware of that but now I want to use the setText(""); statement not outside the cases, so the tabs are renamed when another bottomMenu option is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tabLayout.getTabAt(item.getItemId()).setText("Ds");`

Comment: Would you give me an example how to use it here?

Comment: But in case I have three tabs it just renames either the first, the second or the third one depending on what is selected in the bottom menu, doesn‘t it?

Comment: on each `case` add this line,yes

Comment: When I just set the position manually it works, no need to pass it. Thanks for helping